# Rails ActiveRecord query where " ", "_", and "-" are interchangable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

My goal is to write a Model.find_by_name("foo-bar"), would return a record in the database with the name "foo bar").  I'm struggling to find any information on how this might be accomplished.  I'm using postgresql.  Thanks!

Comment: What if you just query all three?

Comment: It wound't only be three if theres more than 1 space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [regular expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html) to do this:

```
to_match = "foo_bar".sub(/[ \-\_]/, '[ \-\_]')

Model.where("'name' ~ ?", to_match)
```

At least that's the general idea. These kinds of searches will be a lot slower on large tables.

Comment: I didn't know a tilde could be used in a query like that to match against a regex.  It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I linked to the documentation that describes how it's supposed to work. What query is being emitted in `log/development.log`?

Comment: Oops, I overlooked the link.  I just needed the case insensitive operator.  Thanks!